# Develop Spread Polynomials Recursively

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following recursive formula:
$$ S_0 = 0$$
$$ S_1 = \alpha$$
$$ S_{n+1} = 2(1 - 2\alpha)S_n - S_{n - 1} + 2\alpha$$
So $S_2$ is given by:
$$S_{1 + 1} = 2(1 - 2\alpha)S_1 - S_{1 - 1} + 2\alpha$$
Then:
$$S_2 = (2 - 4\alpha)\alpha - 0 + 2\alpha = 4\alpha(1 - \alpha)$$
And we are tasked to show that:
$$S_2(S_2(x)) = S_4(x)$$
I tried:
$$S_2(2(1 - 2\alpha)S_1 - S_{1 - 1} + 2\alpha) = (4\alpha - 4\alpha^2)^2 = 16\alpha^2 - 32\alpha^3 + 16\alpha^4$$
Which is not equal to:
$$S_4 = 16\alpha(1 - \alpha)(1 - 2\alpha)^2 = 16\alpha(1 - 5\alpha + 8\alpha^2 - 4\alpha^3)$$
Any suggestion or pointers in the direction that I should be focusing my attention. My feeling is that I am staring at the solution but its subtlety is just our of my reach.

Comment: There seems to be a mix of $x$s and $\alpha$s; it appears that you're using them interchangeably, so I'll use $x$ to save typing. Since you've already shown that $S_2(x)=4x(1-x)$, you can write simply $$S_2(S_2(x)) = 4\cdot 4x(1-x)\cdot(1-4x(1-x))=16x(1-x)(1-4x+4x^2)=16x(1-x)(1-2x)^2$$ The last expression is, indeed, $S_4(x)$. So, you simply erred somewhere in expanding $S_2(S_2(x))$.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer highlights the elegance of mathematics and thereby underlines its attraction to many. I marvel but unfortunately find myself still looking in from the outside. I hope you have the time to unpack $4⋅4x(1−x)⋅(1−4x(1−x))$. I see the term $(4x(1-x))^2$ but I do not see where we get the $4$ times quantity  nor the term $(1 - 4x(1-x))$ from.

Comment: In determining $S_2(S_2(x))$, we simply replace every $x$ in $4x(1-x)$ with $S_2(x)$, which is $4x(1-x)$. $$4\cdot\color{red}{x}\cdot(1-\color{red}{x}) \quad\to\quad 4\cdot\color{red}{S_2(x)}\cdot (\;1-\color{red}{S_2(x)}\;)\quad\to\quad 4\cdot\color{red}{4x(1-x)}\cdot (\;1-\color{red}{4x(1-x)}\;)$$

Comment: Wow ... I got it now ... thanks for the patience. It is like a double shot of expresso, I need a chaser. Thanks again.